# Emitting sparks or dust at rigid body collisions

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation

I'd like to have automatic particle emission when rigid body objects collide with others (I have many objects). Not that I can find it but I've read of an option under `children` that can spawn others when a particle collides, however I haven't seen anything regarding rigid body collision events.

Can this be done out of the box? With a plugin? Or, last resort, with a small amount of scripting?

Comment: This is not possible yet; That's one of the things Particle Nodes will allow, however they are still in development.

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet possible. However, this is one of the many great things Particle Nodes will allow - these are still [in development](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WV_bLziH1B0) but can be [tested here](http://www.graphicall.org/905).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want ANY rigid body, colliding with any other else rigid body in your scene, to emit particles (i'd love that too), but if the interactions aren't too complex, i guess [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tckapb1Rtgk#t=293) could fit your needs.

Comment: He asks for an automated solution.